# Error 0x000006f8 in Copy() with a file specified in ConEmu GuiMacro

Tags: macros, conemu

While the following works, it copies the visible area of the console text contents to clipboard [as documented](https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Copy),

```
ConEmuC -Guimacro Tab(11, "bash"); Context(); Copy(2, 0)
```

when I try to specify a file like this,

```
ConEmuC -Guimacro Tab(11, "bash"); Context(); Copy(2, 0, "C:\pg\misc\output2.txt")
```

I get an error and it doesn't work correctly. (From "correctly" means, it creates the `output2.txt` but its content is empty)

```
0x000006f8 The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation
```

[image]

Tried on the admin/non-admin cmd.exe, changing the other first/second argment combinations, etc. The same behavior.

I wonder what is wrong with the command or my environment. Thanks for your help.